# I want that every day at the given time value is changed TextField

Tags: objective-c

I want that every day at the given time value is changed TextField and that value is left all day.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    [componentsForReferenceDate setDay:27];
    [componentsForReferenceDate setMonth:10];
    [componentsForReferenceDate setYear:2016];

    NSDate *referenceDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForReferenceDate];

    // set components for time 7:00 a.m.

    NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond ) fromDate: referenceDate];

    [componentsForFireDate setHour:23];
    [componentsForFireDate setMinute:59];
    [componentsForFireDate setSecond:0];

    _utr.text = @"01:57";
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: is that day time or night? I mean its AM/PM formate time or 24-Hour formate?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the user changes their clock or moves between time zones? Are you looking for a timer which fires at a specific point in machine time or user time?

Comment: @SyedeHussaini I want for our city during prayers do. So I need to change the text exactly 00:00. For example today, the morning prayer was 5:45 and 5:44 tomorrow. Today, however, when the user comes to the application where it should see the text 5:45 and when will go tomorrow in the same place text 5:44

Comment: @Itai Ferber this app is not actually on a different time zone. Imagine that I need to show the user the time of sunrise. There TekstFild there exactly 00:00 changing text, sunrise today. For example today, there tomorrow, 6:51 and 6:50, and so every day.

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров What happens then the user gets on a plane and flies to a different country and opens up the app — do you want it to show the time of prayer back home, or relative to where they are now?

Comment: @itai Ferber I want him to see time at home praying.

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров Okay, thanks, that is key information for helping you reach a solution. What decides what time to show? Do you have a database of times to show based on the date, are you calculating it, getting it from a server, etc.?

Comment: @ItaiFerber  I know what time I need to write for each day, but I do not get it from the server. I need to write the time for each day.

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров Yes, but how is that time getting into your app — how do you store that information? It's obviously not the same time every day or else this wouldn't be a question. Is it in a text file, calculated by a formula, etc.?

Comment: @ItaiFerber This is not the same time. It is for each day a different time, and it's all I need to write in the application itself

Comment: @ItaiFerber There are for me what any idea? )) Give me though that be. For example: January 2, 2017 until the text "Hello" ... so that I could work on it

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров The specific way in which you decide what time to write is key to giving a solution; saying "I will figure it out in the app" is not enough to give you a helpful answer. How specifically do you decide what time to show? Again, is there a formula? Is there a list in a text file for every day of the year? What is it?

Comment: @ItaiFerber  Yes, I have a list for each prayer time every day for a whole year ... I can manually enter all in the app ... I need to know how a particular day has caused some text ... Maybe, it's easy, But i can not ...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to set text on your Label at 13:00 then save this time as follows -

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *KEY_TO_SAVE_INTERVAL = @"_time_to_24_hours_check";

if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] > [defaults doubleForKey:KEY_TO_SAVE_INTERVAL]){

    // One Day (24 hours) passed
    //YOUR_LABEL.text = @"YOUR TEXT";


}
else{
    // First time label text set
    //YOUR_LABEL.text = @"YOUR TEXT";
}

//Save time for every label text set

NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
[defaults setDouble:interval forKey:KEY_TO_SAVE_INTERVAL];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: How do I change the text on each day